# How do i set a pane on top during timeline?

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to make sure that when you press the button instead of the red pane overlapping the black pane, the red pane goes under the black pane to give way to the green panel. In short, I would like to make the black pane(header) always remain above everyone else. I tried to use toback() and toFront(), but it doesn’t change anything. I also tried with setViewOrder() but also there no results.

The following is the code:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Prova");

    Pane mainPane=new Pane();

    Pane header=new Pane();
    header.setPrefSize(300, 100);
    header.getStyleClass().add("header");
    header.setViewOrder(1);

    Pane main=new Pane();
    main.setLayoutY(100);
    main.setPrefSize(300, 200);
    main.getStyleClass().add("main");

    Pane p1=new Pane();
    p1.getStyleClass().add("p1");
    p1.setPrefSize(300,200);
    p1.setViewOrder(-1);
    Pane p2=new Pane();
    p2.getStyleClass().add("p2");
    p2.setPrefSize(300,200);
    p2.setViewOrder(-1);

    main.getChildren().addAll(p1);

    Button b=new Button();
    b.setOnAction(e -> {
        main.getChildren().addAll(p2);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0),    new KeyValue(p1.layoutYProperty(), p1.getLayoutY())),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(800), new KeyValue(p1.layoutYProperty(), p1.getLayoutY()-200)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0),    new KeyValue(p2.layoutYProperty(), p2.getLayoutY()+200)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(800), new KeyValue(p2.layoutYProperty(), p2.getLayoutY()))
        );
        timeline.play();
    });

    mainPane.getChildren().addAll(header, b, main);

    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 300, 275);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Style.css:

```
.header {
     -fx-background-color: #0b0b0b;
}
.main {
     -fx-background-color: #121212;
}

.p1 {
     -fx-background-color: red;
}
.p2 {
     -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: If you set the same `viewOrder` do both `Pane`s the property does not have any effect on the relative order of rendering between those nodes. I don't see a call to `toBack`/`toFront` btw. Btw: I recommend you take a look at the console output when clicking the button a second time. Furthermore imho it's cleaner to specify all the `KeyValue`s that apply to the same time using a single `KeyFrame` instead of multiple ones...

Comment: Thx for the reply. 
maybe I did not explain myself well, in the meantime I would like to specify that this is a program made only to understand this problem and I know that the button works only at the first interaction. The problem that I can't understand is because when the red panel goes upwards  instead of going under the black panel it passes over it, and I would like to know if there is a solution.However I don't know if you have tried it but if you try the program you could better understand the problem.I didn't call toback and tofront in this program because I had tried it in another